# Using modules in Snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a Snakefile which I want to use rules from another Snakefile as a module. The problem is, the first rule doesn't get it's input modified and Snakemake throws a MissingInputException

Here's my master Snakefile:

```
from snakemake.utils import min_version
min_version("6.0")

container: "docker://condaforge/mambaforge:4.12.0-0"
pepfile: "pep/config.yaml"
include: "modules/import/Snakefile"

module velocity:
    snakefile: "modules/velocity/Snakefile"


use rule * from velocity as velocity_*

use rule preprocessing from velocity as velocity_preprocessing with:
    input:
        filtered = "results/preprocessing/{pat}.h5ad"
```

And everything runs correctly when the module Snakefile looks like this:

```
rule preprocessing:
    input:
        filtered = "results/preprocessing/{pat}.h5ad"
    output:
        processed = "results/velocity/processed/{pat}.h5ad"
    conda: "envs/velocity.yml"
    script: "python/velocity_preprocessing.py"
```

but not when the input is set to `filtered = "in"` where I get the following Exception:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 1 of [My Directory]/workflow/modules/velocity/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule velocity_preprocessing:
    output: results/velocity/processed/PAWAMB.h5ad
    wildcards: pat=PAWAMB
    affected files:
        in
```

even when the `use rule ... from ... as ... with:` chunk is present. Am I doing something wrong? I would expect both to build the same DAG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting `filtered = "in"`, Snakemake expects a file named "in" to be present in the directory from which the Snakemake is executed. Is this the expected behaviour for your workflow?

Comment: There isn't a file named this, but I was trying to change the input using `use rule ... from module as ... with:`. It seems something is not set up correctly. I'd expect the input file to be changed when using this syntax.

Comment: Hmm, in the question you mention setting `filtered = "in"`... so perhaps you meant to specify a different input filename (rather than "in")?

Comment: Maybe it's not entirely clear. I'm trying to overwrite the input from the module in the master Snakefile. So `filtered = "in"` is meant to just be a placeholder. It seems like when I use the `use rule ... with:` statement, the input is not actually getting overwritten. And I can't tell why. I've followed the documentation and it looks just how it was set up in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `use rule * from velocity as velocity_*`, it imports and defines the rules. The later call `use rule preprocessing from velocity as velocity_preprocessing with:` also imports and defines the rules, but it comes later in the Snakefile.

One recommendation is to change/remove the line:

```py
use rule * from velocity as velocity_*
```